# HTTP Status Code for normal request on AJAX pages

Tags: php, http, http-status-codes

I have a set of php pages that I use specifically for AJAX requests. I was wonder what would be the best HTTP error code for when the page is accessed through a normal request.

I have been using 404 at the moment, but the page does exist.

I was leaning towards either `403 - Forbidden` or `501 - Not Implemented`.

Comment: Why not a redirect to a page that does exist? That way the person doesn't end up at a dead end.

Comment: i see adecuate using 403 as default error for non ajax requests

Comment: how do you know when a client use a non-ajax request, in the server .... just asking.

Comment: @Rafael, yeah I am checking that the request was AJAX based on the server, before I do anything with the data. Just want to provide (and log) and appropriate error for non-AJAX request

Comment: As Rafael said: what's the point? Why not serve the same content to everybody? And how do you define "AJAX" request?

Comment: @JulianReschke because the content returned is a JSON object for use with in the application. This isn't really appropriate to serve to everyone...

Comment: I don't see the point of special-casing. If it's critical to show browser users something, then just consider doing content negotiation and send HTML with the same data. (Should help with debugging as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`406 Not Acceptable` might be valid in this case.

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

Comment: Yes, in case it indeed depends on the Accept headers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think status code matter, you can allow it in all cases, but if you really don't want normal users to access it, I'd use `409 - Conflict`

Comment: `409` is more about a conflict with the existing state of a resource

Answer (score 0):

I would use the generic 400 Bad Request status code.